# Parsing Command Line Arguments in C

Tags: c, parsing, command-line, pipe

I am trying to implement a program that takes in a process followed by a string consisting of pipeline commands.  How do I separate the string of commands, into {individual command/any number of arguments arrays}  The "|" is the character that separates the different commands.

For instance, if I put:
pipe ls -lt | cat Lebowski | cd .. .

How would i get the system to recognize that there are three separate command line arguments here to be represented in different pipes.

Comment: have a look at `strtok`

Answer (score 2):

First of all since pipe is a special symbol you need to escape it when passing to a program:

```
pipe ls -lt \| cat Lebowski \| cd .. .
```

in your main function:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

the `argv` contains all these arguments (ls, -lt, |, cat...) at different indices. For example, `argv[0]` is `ls`, `argv[2]` is `'|'`. `argc` is the total number of such arguments.

Comment: the first line of your response outlines what I need to have happen.  I have to parse arguments WITHOUT the "\" separating the arguments

Comment: so you are implementing a shell and reading input with scanf or similar? in that case H2CO3's answer is the one

Answer (score 1):

perreal's answer is very good if you want to do this yourself. There is a function `getopt()` which you can use for this purpose as well and is documented here [getopt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)

Answer (score 1):

The `strtok_r()` function is your friend:

```
char **explode(char *s, const char *sep, size_t *outsz)
{
    size_t allocsz = 4;
    size_t sz = 0;
    char **arr = malloc(allocsz * sizeof(*arr));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        *outsz = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    char *p, *end;
    for (p = srtok_r(s, sep, &end); p; p = strtok_r(NULL, sep, &end)) {
        if (++sz > allocsz) {
            allocsz <<= 1;
            arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) * allocsz));
            assert(arr != NULL); // sorry
        }
        arr[sz - 1] = strdup(p);
    }

    *outsz = sz;
    return arr;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    char sentence[] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
    size_t sz;
    char **arr = explode(sentence, " ", &sz);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since | is a special character to most common shells, you need to quote them (as others have stated). If you quote all the arguments inside of double-quotes such as

> pipe "ls -lt | cat Lebowski | cd .. "

You can parse `argv[1]` with `strtok_r()`.

Comment: I hate to make comments about safety and such, but **please please don't suggest using `strtok()`.** `strtok_r()` is the safe (specifically, reentrant) variant.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for the suggestion. It's been a long time since I've done pure C programming.

Comment: @H2CO3 Fixed after your suggestion ;-)